# ¿como enviar multiples variables a un documento php para configurar impresion de ticket POS?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

debo imprimir en una impresora POS, ya la reconoce e imprime pero mi problema es que necesito enviar los datos de la factura al archivo php para asi poder utilizarlos individualmente y configurar la factura. Hasta ahora no he podido, primera vez que trabajo con Mike42. 
1-Enviar los datos de la factura al archivo php.
2-Recibir los datos y guardarlos individualmente en una variable para organizarlos en el formato.
Al recibirlos correctamente y poderlos guardar en una variable yo los organizo, pero la verdad necesito ayuda con lo antes mencionado, gracias.

Hasta ahora tengo esto:
Javascript

```
function enviarFactura() {
        //Array para dataCliente
        var nombre = $('#nombref').val();
        var cedula = $('#busqueda').val();
        var fecha = $('#fecha').val();
        var entrega = $('#entrega').val();

        var dataCliente = "nombre="+nombre+"&cedula="+cedula+"&fecha="+fecha+"&entrega="+entrega;

        //Array para item1

        var cantidad1 = $('#cantidad1').val();
        var descripcion1 = $('#descripcion1').val();
        var total1 = $('#total1').val();

        var item1 = "cantidad1="+cantidad1+"&descripcion1="+descripcion1+"&total1="+total1;


        //Array para item2

        var cantida2 = $('#cantidad2').val();
        var descripcion2 = $('#descripcion2').val();
        var total2 = $('#total2').val();

        var item2 = "cantidad2="+cantidad2+"&descripcion2="+descripcion2+"&total2="+total2;


        //Array para item3

        var cantida3 = $('#cantidad3').val();
        var descripcion3 = $('#descripcion3').val();
        var total3 = $('#total3').val();

        var item3 = "cantidad3="+cantidad3+"&descripcion3="+descripcion3+"&total3="+total3;

        //Array para item4

        var cantida4 = $('#cantidad4').val();
        var descripcion4 = $('#descripcion4').val();
        var total4 = $('#total4').val();

        var item4 = "cantidad4="+cantidad4+"&descripcion4="+descripcion4+"&total4="+total4;

        //Array para item5

        var cantida5 = $('#cantidad5').val();
        var descripcion5 = $('#descripcion5').val();
        var total5 = $('#total5').val();

        var item5 = "cantidad5="+cantidad5+"&descripcion5="+descripcion5+"&total5="+total5;

        //Array para item6

        var cantida6 = $('#cantidad6').val();
        var descripcion6 = $('#descripcion6').val();
        var total6 = $('#total6').val();

        var item6 = "cantidad6="+cantidad6+"&descripcion6="+descripcion6+"&total6="+total6;

        //Array para item7

        var cantida7 = $('#cantidad7').val();
        var descripcion7 = $('#descripcion7').val();
        var total7 = $('#total7').val();

        var item7 = "cantidad7="+cantidad7+"&descripcion7="+descripcion7+"&total7="+total7;

        //Array para totales

        var subtotal = $('#sub-total').val();
        var iva = $('#iva').val();
        var totalgral = $('#total-suma').val();

        var totales = "subtotal="+subtotal+"&iva="+iva+"&totalgral="+totalgral;


        if (totales != "") {
            $.post("../ticketPrinter/mike42/escpos-php/example/interface/ticketPrint.php", 
                {"cliente":dataCliente, "producto1":item1, "producto2":item2, "producto3":item3, producto4:item4, "producto5":item5, "producto6":item6, "producto7":item7, "totales":totales},
                function(data) {
                    console.log('Procesado');
                }); 
        } else { 
            console.log('error de busqueda');
        };
    };
```

PHP

```
<?php
/* Change to the correct path if you copy this example! */
session_start();
    require('../../../../../procesos/conexion.php');
    $idusuario=$_SESSION['usuario'];
require __DIR__ . '/../../autoload.php';
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;

  $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("POS58");
  $printer = new Printer($connector);

    // DATOS CLIENTE
    $nombre= $_POST['nombre'];
    $cedula= $_POST['cedula'];
    $fecha= $_POST['fecha'];
    $recibo = $_POST['entrega'];

    // ITEM 1
    $cantidad1 = $_POST['cantidad1'];
    $descripcion1 = $_POST['descripcion1'];
    $total1 = $_POST['total1']; 

    // ITEM 2
    $cantidad2 = $_POST['cantidad2'];
    $descripcion2 = $_POST['descripcion2'];
    $total2 = $_POST['total2']; 

    // TOTALES
    $subtotal = $_POST['subtotal'];
    $iva = $_POST['iva'];
    $totalgral = $_POST['totalgral'];

class Producto{

    public function __construct($nombre, $precio, $cantidad){
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
        $this->precio = $precio;
        $this->cantidad = $cantidad;
    }
}

$productos = array(
        new Producto($descripcion1, $total1, $cantidad1),
        new Producto($descripcion2, $total2, $cantidad2),
    );


$totales = new producto ($subtotal, $iva, $totalgral);


  /* Title of receipt */
$printer -> setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_CENTER);
$printer -> setEmphasis(true);
$printer -> text("SENIAT\n");
$printer -> setEmphasis(false);

/* Name of shop */
$printer -> selectPrintMode(Printer::MODE_DOUBLE_WIDTH);
$printer -> text("Angeluz c.a.\n");
$printer -> selectPrintMode();
$printer -> text("J-41011714-1\n");
$printer -> text("Av. República C.C El Terminal de Pasajeros terrestre - Nivel PB - Local s/n\n");
$printer -> text("Sector Av. República - Ciudad Bolívar - Edo. Bolívar\n");
$printer -> feed(1);

/* Client data*/
$printer -> setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_LEFT);
$printer -> text("Cliente: " . $nombre . "\n");
$printer -> text("RIF/CI: " . $cedula . "\n");
$printer -> text("caja: " . $idusuario . "\n");
$printer -> text("Fecha:" . " " . $fecha . "\n");

/*Receip data*/
$printer -> setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_CENTER);
$printer -> text("FACTURA\n");
$printer -> setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_LEFT);
$printer -> text("Factura N°: " + $recibo . "\n");
$printer -> setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_CENTER);
$printer -> text("______________________________________\n");

                        /*Sale Data*/
$printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_LEFT);
$printer->text($producto->cantidad . "x" . $producto->nombre . "\n");

/*Y a la derecha para el importe*/
$printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_RIGHT);
$printer->text('Bs' . $producto->precio . "\n");
$printer -> text("______________________________________\n");

// Totalizar
$printer -> setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_LEFT);
$printer ->text("Subtotal");
$printer -> setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_RIGHT);
$printer ->text("Bs " . $subtotal . "\n");

$printer -> setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_LEFT);
$printer ->text("IVA 16%" . "\n");
$printer -> setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_RIGHT);
$printer ->text("Bs " . $iva . "\n");

$printer -> setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_LEFT);
$printer ->text("Total" . "\n");
$printer -> setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_RIGHT);
$printer ->text("Bs " . $totalgral . "\n");


$printer -> feed(3);
$printer -> cut();
/* Close printer */
$printer -> close();
```

Comment: La cosa es que pareciera que se envian pero algo debo estar haciendo mal porque no se imprimen los datos en la factura

Comment: fijate que por ajax no estas pasando ningun parametro llamado nombre sino cliente.....{"cliente":dataCliente,.....}

Comment: por ello no obtienes lo datos en php debes coger los valores por el nombre que envias desde javascript(cliente...producto1....etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final encontré la solución yo mismo. solo envié las variables arregladas en una mimificacion de ajax y las recibí en el otro archivo php vía post igualmente y guardando los datos es sus respectivas variables para así ordenarlas en la factura. Quizas hay un metodo mas simple, sin tantas variables en js, por ejemplo obteniendo los elementos por clases, pero asi me funconó.

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 

    $("#imprimir").click(function(){

            $.post("../ticketPrinter/mike42/escpos-php/example/interface/ticketPrint.php", 

            {
                // dataCliente
                nombre: $("#nombref").val(),
                cedula : $("#busqueda").val(),
                fecha : $("#fecha").val(),
                factura : $("#factura").val(),
                // item 1
                cantidad1 : $("#cantidad1").val(),
                descripcion1 : $("#descripcion1").val(),
                total1 : $("#total1").val(),
                // item 2
                cantidad2 : $("#cantidad2").val(),
                descripcion2 :$("#descripcion2").val(),
                total2 : $("#total2").val(),
                // item 3
                cantidad3 : $("#cantidad3").val(),
                descripcion3 : $("#descripcion3").val(),
                total3 : $("#total3").val(),
                // item 4
                cantidad4 : $("#cantidad4").val(),
                descripcion4 : $("#descripcion4").val(),
                total4 : $("#total4").val(),
                // item 5
                cantidad5 : $("#cantidad5").val(),
                descripcion5 : $("#descripcion5").val(),
                total5 : $("#total5").val(),
                // item 6
                cantidad6 : $("#cantidad6").val(),
                descripcion6 : $("#descripcion6").val(),
                total6 : $("#total6").val(),
                // item 7
                cantidad7 : $("#cantidad7").val(),
                descripcion7 : $("#descripcion7").val(),
                total7 : $("#total7").val(),
                // totaltes
                subtotal : $("#sub-total").val(),
                iva : $("#iva").val(),
                totalgral : $("#total-suma").val() },

                function() {
                    console.log('Procesado');
                });  
        });

});
```

PHP

```
// DATOS CLIENTE
    $nombre= $_POST['nombre'];
    $cedula= $_POST['cedula'];
    $fecha= $_POST['fecha'];
    $factura = $_POST['factura'];

    // ITEM 1
    $cantidad1 = $_POST['cantidad1'];
    $descripcion1 = $_POST['descripcion1'];
    $total1 = $_POST['total1']; 

    // ITEM 2
    $cantidad2 = $_POST['cantidad2'];
    $descripcion2 = $_POST['descripcion2'];
    $total2 = $_POST['total2'];


   //...y asi sucesivamente con todas las variables
```

Answer (score 0):

Saludos si te fijas estas enviado los datos ya por el metodo POST por lo cual debes recibirlos de la misma manera:

```
 $.post("../ticketPrinter/mike42/escpos-php/example/interface/ticketPrint.php", 
                {"cliente":dataCliente, "producto1":item1, "producto2":item2, "producto3":item3, producto4:item4, "producto5":item5, "producto6":item6, "producto7":item7, "totales":totales},
                function(data) {
                    console.log('Procesado');
                });
```

asumo que con eso envias los datos, para recibirlos seria asi en tu php:

```
$cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
$producto1 = $_POST['producto1'];
$producto2 = $_POST['producto2'];
$producto3 = $_POST['producto3'];
...
...
```

así sucesivamente con los datos que desees, espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Sabia que me dirian eso, la cosa fue que estaba intentando de varias maneras y al subir el ejemplo se me olvido quitar el GET, ya lo cambie